# curl, SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

Is that the TLS of the server's error? I use the "Comodo PositiveSSL" and the browser could access through https. I

I searched for several answers like this, it seems like the prevention of TLS with local-IP.
But I try to test with other sites with "https" that I know and the result is curl could get through all of them (https://google.com, ...)

Answer (score 0):

If other sites work with curl and this specific site works with Chrome then the server is likely not sending all necessary intermediate certificates. Browsers like Chrome are known to work around such misconfigurations, but curl and other tools don't. Check the site with [SSLLabs](https://ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for "chain issues".